# Run Ghostscript (GS) with PostScript as a command line argument (but not a file)

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript, watermark, postscript

I execute a Ghostscript (`gs`) command with the following arguments:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=98 -r96 -dTextAlphaBits=4 \
   -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=target.jpg -f watermark.ps input.pdf
```

where `watermark.ps` is a PostScript file with script like here:

[Is it possible in Ghostscript to add watermark to every page in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243044/is-it-possible-in-ghostscript-to-add-watermark-to-every-page-in-pdf/12596669#12596669)

**Is it possible to use that PostScript inline, I mean putting `watermark.ps` text directly to the command line avoiding the file reading?**

According to this doc http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.18/Use.htm#Input_control it's possible using `-c` or `-s` switches, but I can't figure out how to merge that .ps file to one line? How to treat new lines in PS? Maybe I should use `-c` for every line? I was not able to google any `gs` example with inline PS.

Answer (score 1):

Rather a disjointed questions....

Yes it is possible to add a watermark to every page, no its not simple when the input is PDF, however my answer from the question you quoted should work.

I should give up on trying to do this with -c and -f. What do you think you gain that way anyway ? However the simple answer is that newline is (not surprisingly) simply a white space character in PostScript. Its not a special token, you can replace it with any other white space character.

If you want to use PostScript, then there's no point in googling for **Ghostscript**, you need to look for PostScript. Its a programming language, and Adobe released the specification when they produced the early interpreters, back in the 1980s. The specification (now at level 3) is still available online.

Comment: i googled both post and ghost script - almost all my request redirected to http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.18/Use.htm or just pure Post Script specification

Comment: Well, the PostScript specification is what you need to answer questions regarding PostScript.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your command line, I'm assuming you have a unix shell. You can substitute the result of a command in most shells with `` `cmd args...` `` or `$(cmd args)`.

```
bash> echo $(cat watermark.ps)
```

With gs's `-c <ps-code>` option, you can *inject* the code into the execution at that point.

Comment: "I'm assuming you have a unix shell" - no. Actually it is even not gs command, it is a java library Ghost4J. It uses the same command interface as in command line, but obviously i can't use an input/output stream pipe-line there.

Comment: >inject the code into the execution at that point
could you explain what this means (inject code)?

Comment: "Inject" was probably the wrong word. I meant "insert". ... You can put the `-c code` option between two filenames, and gs will execute the code between the files.